# Why does my DataTables implementation not work correctly with ColumnDefs?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am using [DataTables Server Side](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) to generate a paginated table from my MySQL table.

I am trying to use the [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) option to turn the first column into hyperlinks based on the MySQL results, like so:

```
<td><a href="index.php?result=[mysql result]">[mysql result]</a></td>
```

This is the code I have written to initiate the DataTables table:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "includes/pull_2.php",
            "columnsDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": 0,
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return "<a href=index.php?result=" + full[0] + ">" + full[0] +"</a>"; 
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, although the table is rendering without any errors, it is not making the first column a hyperlink as I expected. Does anybody know why this is not functioning as expected?

This is the table I am testing on: http://clients.serallo.co.uk/formtest/

Answer (score 1):

Parameter is not **columnsDefs**, it is **columnDefs** just change that it will work.